# Apendar linhas em arquivo já existente

Tags: java, io

Estou tentando apendar linhas em um relatório, mas as linhas novas estão sobrescrevendo as antigas.

Classe com método main:

```
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

public class TesteInscricoes {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {


        Equipante gabriel = new Equipante();
        gabriel.setNome("Gabriel");
        Equipante milena = new Equipante();
        milena.setNome("Milena");

        InscricaoDeEquipante inscricaoDeEquipante = new InscricaoDeEquipante();
        inscricaoDeEquipante.inscreveEquipantes(gabriel);
        inscricaoDeEquipante.inscreveEquipantes(milena);
    }
}
```

Classe que faz a inscrição:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

public class InscricaoDeEquipante {

    public void inscreveEquipantes(Equipante equipante) throws FileNotFoundException {

        PrintWriter inscreve = new PrintWriter(new FileOutputStream(new File("Inscricoes.csv")), true);     
        inscreve.append(equipante.getNome());

        inscreve.close();
    }
}
```

No final, o arquivo apresenta apenas o nome "Milena".

Estou começando com java e estou com dificuldades com o IO.

O que eu preciso usar para obter o resultado esperado??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O construtor usado é `FileOutputStream(File)` com apenas um parametro. Esse sempre irá criar um novo arquivo. Para adicionar ao fim do arquivo use o construtor `FileOutputStream(File, boolean)` passando `true` como segundo parâmetro. [Documentação](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html#%3Cinit%3E(java.io.File,boolean)):

> ... If the second argument is true, then bytes will be written to the end of the file rather than the beginning. ...

Exemplo:

```
... new PrintWriter(new FileOutputStream(new File("Inscricoes.csv"), true), true);
```

<sup>*(será que o problema era apenas um `)` na posição errada?)*</sup>

*Nota*: poderia usar o construtor `FileOutputStream(String, boolean)` sem ter que criar uma instancia de `File`.

*Nota 2*: não faz muito senttido usar um `PrintWriter` nesse atual código; mas não sei se pretende adicionar mais dados ao arquivo (separação entre os dados por se tratar de um CSV)

Exemplo com `FileWriter`:

```
Writer inscreve = new FileWriter("Inscricoes.csv", true);
```

<sup>*(não testado, baseado exclusivamente na documentação)*</sup>

Comment: De fato, vejo que errei o construtor onde coloquei o parâmetro `true`. Em relação à segunda nota, escolhi o PrintWriter por achar mais fácil, mas nesse caso o que é recomendado usar??